# How does a finite resistance arise in ideal wires?

Tags: electric-circuits, solid-state-physics, electrical-resistance, conductors, dissipation

If an electric circuit performs a useful work, e.g., powering an electric motor or generating a sound via a speaker, it means energy transfer from the battery/EMF to the device in question. This energy transfer would occur, even if the circuit is made of ideal wires (not necessarily *ideal* as in *ideal conductor*, but simply having very low resistance). The work done in such a circuit could be described *ad-hoc* as a Joule heat in terms of an effective resistance:
$$
P=I^2R_{eff}.
$$
This equation serves as the definition of the effective resistance. It is not however entirely clear to me how this resistance arises in the wires ad how it can be calculated, and I will appreciate the community input about this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question, are you talking about the effective resistance of the device in the circuit?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the effective resistance. Suppose I have my device and I want to calculate its power...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this example will be useful:

In the world of radio engineering, it is important to understand how much radio frequency energy being put out by a transmitter can be transformed into electromagnetic waves by an antenna connected to that transmitter.

For best power transfer, the antenna is sized so it resonates as a half-wave at the frequency at which the transmitter is operating. At this resonant condition, the impedance of the antenna consists of pure resistance (no reactive power).

Part of that pure resistance is simply the ohmic resistance of the wire from which the antenna was fashioned, and the rest of that resistance is *radiation resistance*, which accounts for the power loss from the antenna to the free space surrounding it, in the form of radio waves.

Physically, this radiation resistance "looks" just like ohmic resistance and is mathematically accounted for just like ohmic resistance- except that instead of electrical power being lost from the antenna as I^2R heat in the wire, the power lost from the antenna wire due to radiation resistance is radiated away from it as electromagnetic energy in the form of radio waves.

Comment: This is a very good example - one could write down the joint system of equations for the circtit with antenna and the electromagnetic field, and the resistance would arise naturally! This also gives a hint for the missing inredient in my reasoning: for any kind of device there is necessarily a feedback force with which they act on the circuit (since the coupling energy contains the variables of both), which is what creates the resistance.

Comment: Same argument applies for loudspeakers. An "8 ohm" loudspeaker measures out at about 6.8 ohms on an ohmmeter; the remaining 1.2 ohms is the *radiation resistance* of the speaker cone.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this definition is useful only for determining the effective resistance. Devices I can think of are usually described through their power since that's what they're useful for (think of light bulbs, for example, or a motor). To me, it seems that evaluating a priori the effective resistance of a device, without involving measurements of its power would need a model which is specific to that device and perhaps too complicated to actually be solved.